# Django bootstrap4 - Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form

Tags: django, forms, bootstrap-4

I am getting the following Bootstrap exception

```
'Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.'
```

when running the following code from [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap4/) tutorial:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<form action="/url/to/submit/" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Is the second'form' in 'bootstrap_form *form*' supposed to reference/point to something? Is it a variable? What is a valid django form? I checked several posts and answers on this issue, but haven't been able to make sense of this error.

EDIT View code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'hello_world.html', {})
```

Comment: Can you share your view that is rendering this template?

Comment: @IainShelvington updated OP with view code.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and it takes me nearly whole day to figure out.

The Quickstart part of django-bootstrap4 is not very starter-friendly.

`{% bootstrap_form form %}`

The `form` is a parameter, which should be transfered from views.py. In your situation, `form` should be added to `return render(request, 'hello_world.html', {})`

1. create a file called `forms.py` and put following code in it.

(forms.py should be put in the same folder of views.py)

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

2. modify `views.py` and add the following code:

```
# ...
from .forms import NameForm

# ...
def hello_world(request):
    form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'hello_world.html', {'form': form})
# ...
```